# Meaning/Conjugation of "servirese"

Tags: verbs, meaning

From the prologue of Francesca Caccini's *La Liberazione di Ruggiero*:

> Meco venite, e con sonore voci, /
>   Numi dell'acque, reverite in pace, /
>   Chi vinse in guerra il Moscovita e'l Trace, /
>   E servirese i Tartari feroci.

Is "servirese" an archaic conjugation of "servire"? (Passato remoto forse?) It doesn't make grammatical sense as an infinitive + reflexive pronoun, and furthermore it is set musically so that the 3rd syllable is stressed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe there is a missing space and the correct phrase is *servi rese*, that is, “enslaved”; literally, *servi rese* = *rese servi* = “made slaves” (the inversion is usual in poetry).

Comment: Ah brilliant, that has to be it! It's hyphenated together in the score but this answer makes much more sense, thank you!